# Split an object into arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently writing a library using jQuery, and I'm facing a wall I can't pass alone.

First, here is some code :

```
(function($) {
// default options
var defaults = {
    option1: "what ever",
    option2: "what ever"
};

// available methods
var methods = {
    method1: function(param1) {
        console.log(param1);
        /* ... */
    },
    method2: function(param1, param2) {
        console.log(param1);
        console.log(param2); // gives undefined
        /* ... */
    }
};

// Where magic happens
$.fn.pskChart = function(params) {
    if (methods[params] != undefined) {
        if (this.length > 0) {
            return $(this).each(function(i) {
                return methods[params].apply($(this), Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
            });
        }
    } else {
        $.error("Method " + params + " doesn't exist for pskChart");
    }
}
})(jQuery);


$("#sample").pskChart("method1", "param1"); // will work
$("#sample").pskChart("method2", "param1", "param2"); // won't work
```

**This code is working in case I provide only two parameters** (method and another parameter), **but won't work if I have more parameters**

I understand that `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)` returns only one object containing all the remaining arguments.

In the second example, `method2` will be called with only one parameter that contains `["param1","param2"]`

---

I would like to "split" this object in order to provide as many parameters I have.

I feel like `methods[params].apply($(this), Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));` but I have no clue how to fix it.

Note that I could have an *infinite* (or at least *big*) number of parameters (in addition to the method, that will always be first).
Playing with `Array.slice` would not be a great (nor proper) solution.

Comment: Side note: jQuery plugins should always return `this` (barring having a  good reason not to). Your `pskChart` function doesn't.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I actually return something in each method (in the `/* ... */`- which is not relevant for my question)

Comment: Returning things from your methods is pointless, unless you want to return `false` to stop the `each` loop. (You should almost certainly remove the `return` from the line inside the `each`.) I'm talking about `pskChart`, not the methods.

Comment: I should have been more clear: Your `pskChart` method's return value is wrong in a couple of ways: If `pskChart` has the method but there are no elements in the jQuery set, it returns `undefined`; it should return `this`. If there are elements in the set, it returns a *new* jQuery object for the set (because you're using `$(this)` where `this` is already a jQuery set); it should return `this`, not a new object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why it would work even with just one parameter, as you're using the wrong `arguments` object.

Instead (see comments):

```
// Where magic happens
$.fn.pskChart = function(params) {
    var args; // **Change** We'll use this below
    if (methods[params] != undefined) {
        if (this.length > 0) {
            // **Change** Grab the arguments here, in the `pskChart` function
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
            return $(this).each(function(i) {
                // **Change** Use them here; you can't use `arguments` here
                // because, it will be the arguments to this anonymouus
                // function, not the ones to `pskChart`
                return methods[params].apply($(this), args);
            });
        }
    } else {
        $.error("Method " + params + " doesn't exist for pskChart");
    }
}
```

---

Side note: `params` is a very strange name for an argument you're using as a method name. Perhaps `methodName`?

Side note 2: Rather than repeatedly looking up `methods[params]`, consider using a variable. Large sets may benefit from the reduced work.

Side note 3: This line inside your `each` loop is almost certainly a mistake:

```
return methods[params].apply($(this), args);
```

That will return the return value of the method to jQuery's `each` code. jQuery's `each` code will completely ignore that vallue **unless** it's `=== false`, in which case it will stop the `each` loop. Not at all likely to be what you meant that to do.

Side note 4: Your `pskChart` function, being a jQuery plugin, should return `this` unless it has a good reason for returning something else. Right now, the return value is chaotic: If the set has no elements, you return `undefined` (implicitly); if the set has objects, you return a **new** jQuery object, not `this`, because of this line:

```
return $(this).each(function(i) {
```

There's no reason for using `$()` there, `this` is **already** a jQuery set (which is why the previous line using `this.length` works).

Side note 5: You're missing a semicolon from the assignment statement (e.g., there should be one after the closing `}` on the function expression).

Recommendation:

```
// Where magic happens
$.fn.pskChart = function(methodName) {
    var args, method = methods[methodName];

    if (!method) {
        // Throws
        $.error("Method " + params + " doesn't exist for pskChart");
    }

    if (this.length > 0) {
        args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        this.each(function() {
            method.apply($(this), args);
        });
    }

    return this;
};
```

Comment: Works like a charm, I guess I messed up with some old code I had

Comment: @TouPye: Glad that helped. I added a couple of further notes.